# how to pass data to model class and fetch data from model class - swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, parsing, model

this is my model class for storing data

```
class TeamData {
    let teamName : String
    let image : String
    let nextMatch : String
    let matches : [Match]
}

class Match {
    let oppositeTeam : String
    let matchTimings : String
    let matchId : String
}
```

this is my array of data from which i am fetching data right now (alternate to JSON)

```
var dataArray = [
                ["teamName":"Arsenal",
                  "image":"Arsenal",
                  "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
                  "matches":[
                                ["oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                                 "matchTimings":"121212",
                                 "matchId":"ID 213432"],
                                ["oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                                 "matchTimings":"121212",
                                 "matchId":"ID 213432"]
                            ],
                  "fixtures":[
                                ["oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                                 "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
                                 "HomeTeamScore":"4",
                                 "HomeTeamCards":"True",
                                 "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
                                 "fixtureId":"ID 213432”    
                            ]
                 ]
    ]]
```

this is how i am fetching data using for loop from dataArray. but now i dont now how i can pass data to model class and then use model class in tableview for displaying this data. i create init() for data model but i am confused how to get the data for  matches : [Match] .

```
for data in dataArray {
    if let matches = data["matches"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for data in matches {

        }
    }

    if let fixtures = data["fixtures"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for data in fixtures {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought of using `Codable`. That will make your things way easier.

Comment: yeah but data is not coming from any API, i am using array

Comment: If you will ultimately getting data in JSON format then kindly change your `dataArray` into corresponding JSON String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your object in dataArray is just array of strings and not object with properties. So if you want to decode it to your custom class edit you dataArray like this

```
    [{"teamName":"Arsenal",
      "image":"Arsenal",
      "nextMatch":"in 2 days",
      "matches":[{"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                  "matchTimings":"121212",
                  "matchId":"ID 213432"},

                 {"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                 "matchTimings":"121212",
                 "matchId":"ID 213432"}],
       "fixtures": {"oppositeTeam":"teamName",
                   "oppositeTeamScore":"7",
                   "homeTeamScore":"4", /* I renamed this with small first letter*/
                   "homeTeamCards":"True", /* I renamed this with small first letter*/
                   "oppositeTeamCards":"false",
                   "fixtureId":"ID 213432”}
        }
    ]
```

Use codable protocol on your classes

```
class TeamData: Codable {
    var teamName : String
    var image : String
    var nextMatch : String
    var matches : [Match]
    var fixtures : Fixtures
}

class Match: Codable {
    var oppositeTeam : String
    var matchTimings : String
    var matchId : String
}
```

also don't forget to create class Fixtures

```
class Fixtures: Codable {
    var oppositeTeam : String
    var oppositeTeamScore : String
    var homeTeamScore : String
    var homeTeamCards : String
    var oppositeTeamCards : String
    var fixtureId : String
}
```

and now somewhere where you have your dataArray decode this JSON array with JSON decoder

```
let teamDataArray = JSONDecoder().decode([TeamData].self, from: dataArray)
```

Now if you need for example get first TeamData object and get its image say

```
teamDataArray[0].image /* This value should be Arsenal */
```

Comment: and how i can access data from model class to display in tableview @Robert Dresler